# Difference between print/saveas and export

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I'm doing some plots in Matlab, but when exporting to pdf I'm not getting the same results I see on my screen. In particular, I'm trying to put white edges to the legend.

```
leg1 = legend(names);
set(leg1,'EdgeColor',[1 1 1]);
```

When using "File -> Save As -> Out.pdf" the edges are white, but when I use `saveas(gca,'Out.pdf')` or `print -dpdf Out.pdf` the edges are black. What is Matlab doing when I use the export function? How can I have the same results from the command line?

---

Edit

Just to be clear, this is an example code:

```
plot(rand(10,1))
leg1 = legend('Data');
set(leg1,'EdgeColor',[1 1 1]);
print -dpdf Out.pdf
```

The pdf file shows this: 
[image]

Which clearly is not the intended figure, and its different from the one showed by Matlab. When I use the "File -> Save as" option, the edge of the label is displayed correctly.

Comment: If a format is supported by `print`, like in your case, then also `saveas` uses `print` internally. To help you, please post a full executable minimal example and a screenshot of your problem and tell us which MAtlab version you're using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When saving from the "File -> Save As " it runs an mfile `filemenufcn`.

You can call it diretly from the commandline:

```
filemenufcn ( figHandle, 'FileSaveAs' )
```

Its a shame Mathworks don't allow you to pass in a filename to save directly...

You can investigate that function to see what the function is doing to the figure before its being saved.

FYI: In the latest Matlab (R2015a) the final code that does the actual saving to pdf is `hgexport`. (Which is a p-code file but it does have some basic help)  You could directly invoke that at the commandline.

You should also look at [export_fig](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/23629-export-fig) which is an excellent tool for exporting graphics to file.

Answer (score 1):

I am afraid that the other answer does not really answer the question. This is how you "print" white line/text to a file: run

```
set(gcf, 'InvertHardCopy', 'off');
```

before using the `print` command.

However, for your specific case, since you are just trying to hide the box borders, the better way to do it is

```
legend boxoff
```

or

```
legend('boxoff')
```

Source: https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/102484-why-does-my-white-text-become-black-in-my-figure-when-printing-to-an-emf-file-in-matlab-7-5-r2007b